# URL masking/mapping to include relative folder path

Tags: dns, cname, redirect, url-mapping

I have web pages in

```
www.uglyhostdomain.com/projectname/version2/index.html
```

and own the domain

```
www.prettydomain.com
```

Is it possible to configure them in some way such that www.prettydomain.com acts as though the www.uglyhostdomain.com/projectname/version2/ folder does.

I understand this uses some combination of CNAME and/or URL masking (cloaking?) and URL mapping but it isn't clear to me which configuration to use.

I.E. can I use www.prettydomain.com/index.html and www.prettydomain.com/login.html to show the pages being served from www.uglyhostdomain.com/projectname/version2/

Hopefully I didn't butcher the question too badly. Any help appreciated.